# $|p(y)| > |y| + |\delta y|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(y)$ be a complex polynomial of degree at least two and $\delta$ some complex number. I want to show

$$|p(y)| > |y| +|\delta y|$$

for $|y| > \kappa$ sufficiently large. I have tried applying the triangle or reverse triangle inequalities but I can't seem to get the absolute values to match up.

Comment: $|\frac{p(y)}{(1+\delta)y}| \to \infty, |y| \to \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment, since $p(y)$ is a polynomial of degree greater than or equal to two, $\left| \frac{p(y)}{y} \right |\to \infty$ as $|y| \to \infty$.
We can choose sufficiently large $|y|$ so $\left| \frac{p(y)}{y} \right | > 1+|\delta|$ and the result follows.